# Table HTML overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a better looking memberlist for my website. http://www.pimpkings.com/memberlist

```
<table width="100%" rules="cols" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">
<colgroup span="5" </colgroup>
  <tr>
<td class="{memberrow.ROW_CLASS}" td align="center" width="200" valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<span class="gen"><a class="gen" href="{memberrow.U_VIEWPROFILE}">{memberrow.USERNAME}</a></span>
      <div class="avatar mini"><a href="{memberrow.U_VIEWPROFILE}">{memberrow.AVATAR_IMG}</a></div>
  <align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="200">
    <center><font face="verdana" decoration="yes" size="2" color="white">Information</font></center>
    <br /><font face="verdana" size="1" color="green">Interest:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
<span class="gen">{memberrow.INTERESTS}</span>
    <br /><font face="verdana" size="1" color="green">Join Date:</font> &nbsp;&nbsp; <br />
<span class="gensmall">{memberrow.JOINED}</span>
    <br /><font face="verdana" size="1" color="green">Last Visited:</font> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <br />
<span class="gensmall">{memberrow.LASTVISIT}</span>
    <br /><font face="verdana" size="1" color="green">Post Count:</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;  <br />
<span class="gen">{memberrow.POSTS}</span>
<align="right" border="0" cellspacing="2" width="200">
  <center> <br /><font face="verdana" size="2" color="green">Contact</font><br /></center>
&nbsp;{memberrow.PM_IMG}&nbsp;
&nbsp;{memberrow.WWW_IMG}&nbsp;
    </tr>
    </td>
    </body>
```

Problem is when I add another

```
 <td>
```

It makes it duplicate the information I am calling upon. I will actually make the code the way i am talking about so when you visit the site you will see what I am talking about. I just don't want it to duplicate any members information. so basically

1. Member 2. Member
2. Member 4. Member
3. Member 6. Member

Is what I mean

not

1.Member 1.Member
2.Member 2.Member

...

Is there any way possible to do this? I am using a forum website and i have access to the CSS stylesheet and where this code is. Maybe a Javascript code??? Please help asap for the code I am doing is for an open site but is needed for a soon be opened site that is being paid for. Please and thank you everyone.

Also any way of making a background image repeat for the members background table??

I'd Like to have 3 columns made that is calling on the variables listed in the code without repeat.

Thanks again

Comment: Can you make the memberlist viewable without making an account ? Regards

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tables.  Welcome to the world of CSS floats.  Here's a shiny new example for you:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tableHold">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.tableHold {
    overflow: auto;
}

.tableHold li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Here's some more information on how things work.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)
[Here's a fiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/j9SRu/)

Comment: Actually members list sound like tabular data in which case there is no reason not to use tables.

Comment: @x64igor A list isn't inherently tabular. Besides, there's no reason not to use CSS floats. ;)

Comment: only reason guys this is tables is because of the forum host i am using. it uses all tables. barely really any divs except inside tables.

Comment: Well, if you want my opinion: I'd rather write things the "standard" way from now on rather than conform to the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="tableHold">
  <div> 1  </div>
  <div> 2  </div>
  <div> 3  </div>
  <div> 4  </div>
  <div> 5  </div>
  <div> 6  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.tableHold {
  overflow: auto;
}

.tableHold div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Try this on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpak